# how to decrease spaces in url references

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing

I used these codes to make url references font smaller. Reference[2] works very well, but reference[3] doesn't work. I am trying to make references more nice and have consistent format.

```
\makeatletter
\def\url@leostyle{%
      \@ifundefined{selectfont}{\def\UrlFont{\sf}}{\def\UrlFont{\small\ttfamily}}}
\makeatother
\urlstyle{leo}
```

[image]

Thank you in advance. 
Rochus

Comment: the default url handling only allows breaks at `/` so unless you change that the best option is to set the references `\raggedright`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).